# Flux and FileInputStream not being closed

Tags: java, reactive-programming, fileinputstream

As per the documentation:

```
  // input file
    Path ipPath = Paths.get("/some/path/large-input-file.txt");
    
    Flux<String> stringFlux = Flux.using(
            () -> Files.lines(ipPath),
            Flux::fromStream,
            Stream::close
    );
```

This code is reading from input flux, but File.lines is not encoded UTF-8. as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35826729/java-malformedinput-exception-on-reading-text-data#35826998), so I used FileInputStream instead as shown on the code below :

```
      // input file
        Path ipPath = Paths.get("/some/path/large-input-file.txt");
        
        Flux<String> stringFlux = Flux.using(
                () -> {
                 final var fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(ipPath.toFile());
                 final var isr=new InputStreamReader(fileInptStream,StandarCharsets.UTF_8);
                 final var bufferReader=new BufferReader(isr);
                return bufferReader.lines();
                       },
                Flux::fromStream,
                Stream::close
        );
```

the issue I'm Facing it the inputfilestream is not closing after processing, please advice

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve the issue:

- use `Files.lines(Path, Charset)` overload
- do the wrapping inside the flux provider and keep the fileInputStream as resource:

```java
Flux<String> stringFlux = Flux.using(
        () -> Files.lines(ipPath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
        Flux::fromStream,
        Stream::close
);
```

```java
Flux.using(() -> new FileInputStream(ipPath.toFile()),
           fileInputStream -> {
                 final var isr = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                 final var bufferReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                 return Flux.fromStream(bufferReader.lines());
           },
           is -> {
               try {
                   is.close();
               } catch (IOException ex) {
                   throw Exceptions.bubble(ex);
               }
           }
);
```

Comment: Thank you Akarnokd the second solution works, File.lines generate errors even with the right chartsets for some files,